# Visual studio: Build action=Content causes error for dll file

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, publish

I am trying to build a project in C# which uses some unmanaged dll files (MSVCRT.DLL, DFORRT.DLL, ...). There is no direct reference to the `MSVCRT.DLL` file in the project(this file is referenced by another dll and not directly by my program)

I want this dlls to be copied to `bin` directory. if i set build action to `Content` i get this error on run time:

> The procedure entry point _wcstoui64 could not be located in dynamic link library msvcrt.dll.

Which is weird. I cant use other build actions because i want my dlls to be published too(`Build action=None` wont cause any error but doesn't let me to publish my dlls)

If i completely remove all references to all the dlls and treat them like data files, or pictures(files that are not used in code but should be copied to the output) again i get the same error.

What is causing the problem? how can i publish my dlls?

Comment: Can you set it to None and then write a PostBuild event script that copies it instead?

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 It is still copied in `None` configuration. But my problem is in publishing. I can't put the `None` file in the `Application files` to be published.

Comment: msvcrt.dll is an operating system DLL, lots of other OS dlls use it.  So by deploying an old copy of it (and there are *lots* of old copies floating around), you'll break such dlls.  Deploying a new copy is not safe either, likely kaboom when the user has an old OS.  Or in other words, you must **not** deploy it and rely on the copy that is included in the OS.  Fingers crossed.  What "doesn't let me to publish" could mean is impossible to guess.